# Does File service stores the data as blob values in Google App Engine using Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have a HTML form like this,

```
<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" />
<input type="submit"value="upload"/>
</form>
```

Using the File service in GAE with below code am storing the data in google app engine.

```
FileService fileService = FileServiceFactory.getFileService();
AppEngineFile file = fileService.createNewBlobFile(mime, fileName);
boolean lock = true;
byte[] b1 = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
int readBytes1;
FileWriteChannel writeChannel = fileService.openWriteChannel(file, lock);
while ((readBytes1 = is1.read(b1)) != -1) {
writeChannel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(b1, 0, readBytes1));
}
writeChannel.closeFinally();
```

Does this File service stores the uploaded file as Blob values in Google App engine.

- Before using the File service i tried with `createUploadUrl()` method directly in HTML form which stored the files as blob values and i can view the blob too using  "View Blob" in the google app engine.
- Now after using this file am seeing only the key of the file, not the option " View Blob"  can anyone say why this happens.

Comment: In this case your are creating a file but you are not storing it as a blob so you are not able to see the file.

Comment: ok if so without using the `createUploadURL()` in HTML form how can i store the file as blob can you suggest me a way

Comment: well you can use apache common file uploading APIs for storing them into appengine as a blob.

Comment: can you provide any reference links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the link below. Here Apache Common File Upload is shown.

[How to handle html5 input multiple in java gae](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13820566/how-to-handle-html5-input-multiple-in-java-gae)